# Change PHP query string delimiter to "#" for use with $_GET?

Tags: php, query-string

In PHP how can I change the query string delimiter from ? to #

I have a basic function:

```
        <?php
        if ($_GET['var'])
        {echo $_GET['var'] ;}
        else
        {echo "default output";}
        ?>
```

but in the URL syntax I need query sting delimiter to be # (instead of ?) like this:

http://example.com/sample.php#var=foo

I'n thinking a change to php.ini ??

I can't find documentation on this anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is nothing to do with PHP here.

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt (do a quick search in there for the word "fragment", and work *with* the many of us working to make the web a more standards-based ecosystem.

Comment: Need to use a # instead of ? specifically recommended by google analytics -- so URLs with query string VARS are not indexed as unique pages when they are really the same page [https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setAllowAnchor]

Comment: @Nemoden -- I'm not a PHP pro, just know that the PHP function in my code works with ? as query string delim, but not # .... seems to be related to PHP. Should I be looking at mod rewrite solutions or something? ... any helps is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to handle that on the client side.

The hash (`#`), and everything beyond it, is *never sent* to the server.

Comment: +1, You can't expect PHP (and should not desire) to be able to change the meaning of the URI.

Comment: Well ... I know that you can change the query string variable separator  in php.ini ... you can have a look here about that :: [http://davidwalsh.name/change-php-query-string-variable-separator-php-ini] ... How might I change it on the client side if you say it can't be done on the server?